# Why does sort algorithm call the wrong function of class?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

When I use the sort function, the method of sort call isn't I want to use.

```
struct Word {
public:
    char* data;
    int count;
    // Parameterized constructor (This is never called)
    Word(char* data_) :
        data(::strdup(data_)), count(1) {
    }
    // Default constructor
    Word() :
        data((char*)"0"), count(1) {
        data = new char[32];
    }
    // Destructor
    ~Word() {
        if (data) {
            delete data;
            data = 0;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
     /*Copy constructor with deep copy*/
    Word(const Word& word) {
        count = word.count;
        data = ::strdup(word.data);
    }
 
    // Lambda copy operator
    bool operator()(Word * a, Word * b) const {
        std::string aStr(a->data);
        std::string bStr(b->data);
        return  aStr < bStr;
    }
    void operator=(Word);
}typeWord;

static std::vector<Word*> s_wordsArray;

int main()
{
   std::sort(s_wordsArray.begin(), s_wordsArray.end(), typeWord);
}
```

Why does sort call the `Word::Word(const Word& word)` method rather than `Word::operator()(Word * a, Word * b)`?

Comment: `sort` calls `Word::Word(const Word& word)` because it takes the predicate by value, and therefore uses the copy constructor to copy `typeWord`. It would have called `operator()(Word * a, Word * b)` had the vector not been empty.

Comment: The default constructor is a bit odd. Why initialize `data` with a string literal and unsafe cast and then immediately overwrite it with a `new` in the body? You could just initialize it with `new` and leave the body empty. The copy constructor also has a memory leak.

Comment: Yeouch, you initialise `data` with either `new[]` or `strdup`, but then clean them all with `delete`, which is wrong (`new[]` requires `delete[]`, `strdup` requires `free` ).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mix between C++ and C (strdup). The Word class can be simplified, and operator() is not a lambda. Also in a lot of cases you won't need new/delete at all.
Example here :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// std::string already has all the functionality you need
// A word is just a std::string without whitespaces.
// 
// Dont use inheritance with standard library types,
// use composition (make std::string a member)

class Word
{
public:
    Word(const char* str) :
        m_str{ str } // no need for strdup, std::string has a valid constructor for this.
    {
        // check if any of the characters is a whitespace
        // last parameter is a lambda https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/
        auto lambda_is_whitespace = [this](const char c) { return is_whitespace(c) };

        // find if string contains any whitespaces
        auto it = std::find_if(m_str.begin(), m_str.end(), lambda_is_whitespace);
        if ( it != m_str.end() )
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("a word cannot contain a whitespace");
        }
    }

    const std::string& str() const
    {
        return m_str;
    }

private:
    // make functions even for simple concepts
    // they make your code more readable
    // and in this case expandable, you can add
    // more checks easily here.
    bool is_whitespace(const char c)
    {
        return c == ' ';
    }

    std::string m_str;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    // make a list of words
    std::vector<Word> words{"the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog" };

    // this is a lambda function
    auto lambda = [](const Word& lhs, const Word& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.str() < rhs.str();
    };

    // call sort
    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), lambda);

    // range based for loop
    // loop over const references of std::string
    // 1) you won't be changing the words
    // 2) the reference avoids copying the strings into a temporary
    for (const auto& word : words)
    {
        std::cout << word.str() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```